# Splitting dynamically created buttons into rows Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a virtual keyboard from scratch.
So far I have a function that creates a button based on a character it's been given:

```
function keyButton(char) { //makes a button out of a string/char
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); //create button
  btn.innerText = char; //fill it with char
  btn.onclick = function () { keyStroke(this); };
  return btn;
}
```

The second part of my code splits a typical qwerty setup and creates a button with each individual letter:

```
var keyList = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
for (i in keyList) //loops through qwerty keyboard and uses keyButton
{
  var button = keyButton(keyList[i]);
  if (i < 11)
    //give that an element which identifies it as first row
   //document.body.appendChild(button) 
  else if (i < 20)
    //give that an element which identifies it as second row
  else {
    //give that an element which identifies it as third row

  }
```

I am trying to make it so that buttons aren't all one next to another but rather separated in columns of 10 keys, then 9 keys, then 7 keys. I don't know where to start to achieve this. 
Thanks fo the help!

Comment: Put your row structure in an array [10,9,7] and then use these values to loop. First row 10 time, second 9, third 7 and so on ..

Comment: @Daniel The looping works, I just don't know what element I can use to distinguish between the first second and last row. Ideally, I would create a seperate id for each and call them in my body.

Comment: Without knowing how you loop it is hard to say, but having an array as I suggested also also has the index of its values that you could exploit.

Comment: @Daniel as shown in the second piece of code, I am looping with `for (i in keyList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function keyButton(char, num) { 
  var btn = document.createElement("button"); 
  btn.innerText = char; 
  btn.onclick = function () { keyStroke(this); };
  btn.dataset.num = num;
  if(num == 10 || num == 19) {
   btn.className = 'break';
  }
  keyboard.appendChild(btn);
  
  return btn;
}

var keyList = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM";
var keyboard = document.getElementById('keyboard');
for (i in keyList) //loops through qwerty keyboard and usesn
{
  keyButton(keyList[i], i);
 }
```

```css
button {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
button.break {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="keyboard"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using it on an editor. Nothing appears

Comment: Did you change `div#keyboard` to your wrapper?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I put the first segment in the head in a text/javascript script tag, the second in stylesheet tag and the last in between the body tags.

Comment: In my code example all buttons added in <div id="keyboard"></div>
Change `var keyboard = document.getElementById('keyboard');` to your wrapper

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't understand. The line you suggested I put in my wrapper is already in my javascript code. This is definitely the correct answer, as the keyboard is formatted properly and is given an id, but I don't know how to implement it. Do you mind editing your answer posting the complete code or explaining where I am missing something? Thanks you so much

Comment: Just create on your page div block with id = keyboard, copy my code and it would work properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130435/discussion-between-pete-and-boris-p).